# Why does current flow along a wire instead of a resistor right next to it?

Tags: arduino-uno, button, resistor

I am having trouble understanding exactly what is going on in a circuit where when a button is pressed an LED goes on. Also, I have the Arduino UNO.

The schematic can be seen at:

[2:36](https://youtu.be/ksNbEuhO4fU&t=156) of this video: [Arduino Tutorials: Control a LED with a Button](https://youtu.be/ksNbEuhO4fU).

[image: Fritzing of complete circuit]

So, the part that I don’t understand is, how come when the button is clicked and the current can pass through, the current doesn’t go through the pull down resistor and instead goes along the input wire?

[image: Pull down resistor on input]

I’m a beginner but do understand concepts like voltage, amps, resistors, Ohm’s law, etc. So answers don’t have to be super simple, but simple enough that I can understand them. Thanks!

Comment: You may have the arduino, but the question is off topic.  Please ask the question at Electrical Engineering SE.

Comment: The input pin has a very high resistance, so that nearly no current is flowing into it. Effectively the microcontroller is doing a voltage measurement. It measures the voltage over the pulldown resistor.

Comment: Some current is flowing though the pull-down resistor, but the power supply has no problem producing this little bit of current, so the voltage before the pull-down resistor will remain a stable 5 Volt. So the voltage at the Arduino input will be 5Volt while the button is pressed. Once the button is released any "stray" voltage will flow though the resistor, so the voltage at the input pin will become 0 Volt

Comment: Please, can you forget everything that you "learned" from that video. The explanation in that video is wrong and confusing. The way the video explains how the current flows is utter nonsense. You can start with the arduino examples, they are in the menu of the arduino program and also online: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples Start for example with "Button" in section "2. Digital".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, the part that I don’t understand is, how come when the button is clicked and the current can pass through, the current doesn’t go through the pull down resistor and instead goes along the input wire?

Simple: It *does* go through the pull down resistor. But  it *also* goes down the "input" wire.

For simplicity you can imagine that the input is simply a very large resistor. Say, 1MΩ.

The circuit can then be simplified as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIMf1I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Contrary to popular belief, current does *not* take the path of least resistance. It takes *all possible* paths. The quantity of current through each path is proportional to the resistance of the paths.

In this example we have two paths - one with 10kΩ and one with 1MΩ.  That's a ratio of 1:100, and the current will be split accordingly.

You can calculate the current that flows through each resistor simple using Ohm's Law because the wires and switch are (in an ideal world) just not there. The 5V is directly connected across each of the resistors.

So for the 10kΩ resistor the current through is is:

```
     V      5
I = --- = ----- = 0.0005 = 500µA
     R    10000
```

And for the 1MΩ it is of course 100x smaller (I'll let you do the maths for that if you want to check), so 5µA.

The full current that the circuit takes is 505µA, with it split between the two resistors.

With the Arduino instead of the 1MΩ resistor it's exactly the same (though the current values may vary somewhat).  500µA flows through the 10kΩ resistor, and "some tiny current" flows through the Arduino.

However, with all that said, the Arduino really doesn't care about the current. All it cares about is the voltage. With the button pressed both the input and the 10kΩ resistor are connected directly to the 5V supply - so the Arduino reads that as "HIGH". When you release the button the input is now connected to ground through the 10kΩ resistor, but there's no current to flow, so there's no voltage across the resistor (the voltage across a resistor is proportional to the current flowing through the resistor - Ohm's Law), so it's as if the input is connected directly to ground - and the Arduino reads that as "LOW".

To be more technically accurate the input of the Arduino is actually more akin to a tiny capacitor.  When you apply 5V to the input it charges that capacitor up. Once it reaches 60% of 5V the Arduino recognises it as a "HIGH" signal.

When you release the button that capacitor is then connected to ground through the resistor, and it discharges through that resistor. Once it drops to 30% of 5V the Arduino sees it as being "LOW".

If you don't have the pull-down resistor, when you remove the 5V from the input that capacitor is still charged. So the Arduino still sees it as a HIGH. The charge in the capacitor will slowly bleed away until it's low enough to be seen as low.

But, (and it's a *big* but), the capacitor is very sensitive and can be charged up again by ambient energy around the place (radio waves, static electricity, etc). It can harvest enough energy from the environment to get back up to the 60% of 5V and be seen as "HIGH" again. This is known as "Floating", and is something you do *not* want in your circuit. The input "flaps around" between HIGH and LOW with no control.  Which is why the pull-down resistor is absolutely essential.

Comment: I have one question about this answer, doesn’t the voltage drop across the LED or resistors or something like that, I just watched a video and it made me confused about this answer.

Comment: LEDs are a special case. They are in the "non linear" category, and you shouldn't worry about them at the moment. As for "voltage drop", yes, and it is. In simple terms: Ohm's Law has three variables. At any one time two of those variables are fixed, and you are calculating the third. In the circuit above the voltage is fixed and the resistance is fixed - so the current is what you would calculate. The voltage is 5V simply because it is 5V. The resistance is 10kΩ because it's a 10kΩ resistor. The combination of those two values causes 500µA to flow. ... cont ...

Comment: Of course, if you knew that there was 500µA flowing through a 10kΩ resistor then you could calculate that there was 5V being dropped across it.  The 5V in the circuit above is called a *constant voltage supply*. That is because it is always 5V (unless you overload it of course). The current that the supply gives out varies depending on the *load* (the values of the resistors in this example).

Comment: So, you are saying that the reason that it doesn’t drop is only because we already know that there are 5V? Could you please explain, sorry, I’m really trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: It *does* drop. One side of the resistor is 5V. The other side is 0V (ground). The difference is 5V, and that is what is "dropped" across the resistor. The fact that the 5V is fixed in stone means that the current is determined by the resistance and the voltage in the formula I=V/R.

Comment: I promise I’ll try not ask another question, I’m really sorry. But how do you know that there are 0V on the other side of the resistor. Sorry. Is there a place I can understand this or figure out what is going on?

Comment: Because that is "ground" - a point in the circuit which we have chosen to measure all voltages against. The "reference" point of the circuit. "Ground" isn't anything special - it's simply a place we pick in the circuit to be that reference point. Typically it's the point of lowest potential, such as the `-` terminal of a battery, etc. Since "GND" has already been designated by the power supply that's connected (USB, for example), we just pick that as our refrerence point.  The 5V is not "5V" - it's "5V with respect to ground".

Comment: The "bottom" of the resistor is connected direct to ground. Ground is 0V different to Ground (how can something be different to itself?), so that point is 0V. The 5V is 5V higher than the potential at the ground point, so we say that is 5V with respect to ground. Since everything is *always* "with respect to ground" we never say "with respect to ground" and just take it as read.

Comment: To put it another way: A 9V battery isn't "9V" because the `+` terminal has 9V at it. It's 9V because the `+` terminal has 9V more potential than the `-` terminal. It only becomes 9V when you take that `-` terminal as the reference point. You could just as well take the `+` terminal as the reference point - at which moment the battery becomes a "-9V" battery, becuase the `-` terminal has 9V *less* potential than the `+` terminal. It's all relative. So when we pick a "ground" reference it makes sens to use one that gives the power supply a meaningful value.

Comment: I think we had a misunderstanding, I’m wondering why the voltage isn’t dropping across the resistors and 5V is still going into the input?

Comment: 5V is dropping across the resistors. You have 5V (with respect to ground) on the top of it, and 0V (with respect to ground) at the bottom of it. That's 5V from one side to the other. Ergo 5V "dropped". But that doesn't mean that the top of the resistor will no longer be 5V. It *has* to be, for there to be 5V *across* the resistor.

Comment: Ok, this is the final part, I have done the math to clear up my question. Using the math shown here https://youtu.be/hqHvRCCsWU8 I made the resistance of the input wire be V(little r2, no way to format here) and assuming this is about 1 million ohms, and the 10k ohm wire be V(little r2, again no way to format here). Then doing the math I get that 4.95 volts are going into the input wire and .0495 volts are dropping across the 10k oh right resistor. Is this correct? If it is it is what I was trying to say and why I was questioning the fact that you said 5V went into the input wire.

Comment: No, that is not correct. You are looking at tutorial for *series* resistors. This is *parallel* resistors. There can be nothing *but* 5V going to the input, since the input is *directly connected to 5V*.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much, one more thing, though if there is a 1 million ohm resistor (basically) at the input and the voltage drops to 0 (parallel circuit) then if the voltage is zero how does the arduino read that as HIGH? @Majenko

Comment: The voltage at the input is **NOT** zero. It is 5 Volts. It is zero at GROUND. The input is not connected to ground. It is connected to 5V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92570/discussion-between-beastcoder2-and-majenko).

Answer (score -1):

the answer is within the question,
Electrons will quite happily travel along a wire until they hit resistence as in a resistor.
where there is less resistence too flow that is the path they will take.
The path of least resistence you might say.

Comment: That seems misleading, because the current will not flow only through the path with the least resistance. Instead the current is divided between all paths relative to their resistance.

Comment: agreed but at that level of understanding it seemed a fair answer

Comment: Sorry Jamie, but you are sending a beginner down the wrong path.

Comment: ok but please construct a clearer more concise answer

Comment: @Jot he's sending the user down the path of least resistance...